# how to console.log(data); in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have to use the function console.log(data); in my javascript, but it dosent work. Does someone know how to do it? I have just edited my question to some more informations
best Regards From Julie

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $(".datepicker" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      onSelect: function(date, instance){

      },
    });

    $("input[name=endDate]").datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      onSelect: function(date, instance){
        $.post( "../getHoursSQL", {start:$("#startDate").val(),end:$("#endDate").val()}, function( data ) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
          $( "#startresult" ).html( data );
        },'json');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" id="myForm" action="../getHoursSQL">
    Start Date:
        <input type="text" name="startDate" class="datepicker"/><br/>                     
    End Date:
        <input type="text" name="endDate" class="datepicker"/><br/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
        <div id="startresult"></div>
        <div id="endresult"></div>
</body>
```

Console Print:
[image: Console Print]

My Servlet:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@WebServlet("/getHoursSQL")
public class getHoursSQL extends HttpServlet{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) 
        throws ServletException, IOException{

        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/NekiWork";
        Connection connection=null;

        try {
            //Load database driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            //Connection to the database
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", ""); 
            //Getting the data from database

            String sql = "SELECT *, (Day_hours + (Day_minutes / 60)) AS Allday_hours FROM Workdata "
                    + " WHERE Date = ? AND Date = ? ";
            PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");

            java.util.Date util_startDate = format.parse( req.getParameter("startDate") );  
            java.sql.Date sql_startDate = new java.sql.Date( util_startDate.getTime() );

            java.util.Date util_endDate = format.parse( req.getParameter("endDate") );      
            java.sql.Date sql_endDate = new java.sql.Date( util_endDate.getTime() );

                pst.setDate( 1, sql_startDate );
                pst.setDate(2, sql_endDate );
                System.out.println(req.getParameter("startDate"));                          
                System.out.println(req.getParameter("endDate"));

                //Show the result from database

                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

            float Allday_hours_sum = 0;
                while (rs.next()){                                      
                    Allday_hours_sum += rs.getFloat("Allday_hours"); 

                }   
                res.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");          
                res.getWriter().print(Allday_hours_sum); 

                pst.close();

        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e){

            System.out.println("Couldn't load database driver: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("SQLException caught: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {

            try {
                if (connection != null) connection.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException ignored){
                System.out.println(ignored);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

POST SERVLET CONSOLE IMAGE
[image]

Comment: in which browser console you are checking the data

Comment: Is your page returning anything? Is your query working? Do you see anything on the Javascript console?

Comment: `console.log(data)` is perfectly valid javascript. My best guess is that the `$.post` callback is never executed for some reason (or that you are not checking the console).

Comment: I just took a screenshot of my console. Can anybody say something more about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment Don't worry about `console.log`. Look at response tab of the network tab in your browsers developer console.

Check to see of anything is returned by `getHoursSQL`

Btw shouldn't that by `getHoursSQL.php` or similar ?

Edit:

`getHoursSQL.java` in your case

Comment: Hello thanks for your time. I just took a screenshoot of the console network tab. The picture is in my picture. Does it look okay?